# Definition of "polynomial" in Lambek's 1980 paper "From λ-Calculus to Cartesian Closed Categories"

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory

I have been trying to decode an old paper of J. Lambek from 1980: "From λ-Calculus to Cartesian Closed Categories".

The first proposition in the paper concerns some early results in combinatory algebra and reads as follows:

Every polynomial $\varphi(x)$ over a Schonfinkel algebra $A$ can be written in the form $f^{\wr} x$, where $f \in |A|$.

and the second is similar, but for "Curry" algebras.

In the context of this material, what kind of objects would the "algebra" and "polynomial" be? It's never really spelled out in the paper and I assume I'm supposed to just know from whatever background I should have picked up before reading the paper, which I have clearly not done.

I've done some snooping around but can't find any other exposition on combinatory logic that uses this sort of algebraic language.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: A polynomial is an expression containing free variables (in this case, $x$) and with constants taken from the given algebra ($A$). This is not quite standard terminology. A Schönfinkel algebra is a particular kind of combinatory algebra.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE. Can you provide the exact name of the paper?

Comment: The title of the paper is "From λ-Calculus to Cartesian Closed Categories."

I should have included the quotes in my question, sorry about that.